# 'Unable to open the physical file' error trying to attach DB to Microsoft SQL Server on Linux for Docker Engine using mssql-cli

Tags: sql-server, docker, t-sql

I am running [Microsoft SQL Server on Linux for Docker Engine](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) which I am accessing through an OSX host machine using [mssql-cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/mssql-cli).

I am trying to attach an existing database for which I have the .mdf and .ldf files.

However, when I run the command

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDb  
    ON (FILENAME = '/path/to/MyDb.mdf'),   
    (FILENAME = '/path/to/MyDbLogs.ldf')   
    FOR ATTACH;
```

I get the error:

```
Unable to open the physical file "/path/to/MyDb.mdf". Operating system error 2: "2(The system cannot find the file specified.)".
```

I have verified the file does exist at that location on the host machine e.g.

```
$ test -e /path/to/MyDb.mdf && echo file exists || echo file not found
file exists
```

I also attempted mounting the folder containing the DB in the docker container in case it is looking for it in there but in this case I get the error:

```
Unable to open the physical file "/app/path/to/MyDb.mdf". Operating system error 87: "87(The parameter is incorrect.)".
```

Any idea what is causing these errors given I have verified the file is at the location, is there something special about file paths when using OSX or Microsoft SQL Server on Linux for Docker Engine?

Comment: Does the account that the SQL Server Agent is running under have permissions to the location above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured this out now, the missing step was that the backup files need to the copied into the Docker container.

e.g.

`docker exec -it containerName mkdir /var/opt/mssql/backup`

`docker exec -it containerName cp /local/path/to/files containerName:/var/opt/mssql/backup`

Then once connected to the database run the query pointing to the paths in the container e.g.

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDb  
    ON (FILENAME = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/MyDb.mdf'),   
    (FILENAME = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/MyDbLogs.ldf')   
    FOR ATTACH;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and searching about the problem, found a solution: do the same but without the *.ldf file. Like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE NewDb
    ON (FILENAME = '/var/opt/mssql/data/Olddb.mdf')
    FOR ATTACH;
```

I'm using Azure Data Studio for Linux Ubuntu 18.